# What's this matrix transformation called?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, conditional-probability, stochastic-matrices

Given an augmented matrix
$$M = [A \mid X] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 a & b & x\\  
 c & d & y  
\end{array}\right],$$

there's an associated augmented matrix defined like so $$M' = [A' \mid X'] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 \dfrac{ax}{ax+cy} & \dfrac{cy}{ax+cy} & ax+cy\\  
 \dfrac{bx}{bx+dy} & \dfrac{dy}{bx+dy} & bx+dy
\end{array}\right],$$

as long as neither of the denominators vanish. It's probably best to assume $x,y>0$ and $a,b,c,d \geq 0$ together with $a + b = 1$ and $c + d = 1$ to prevent division by zero.

Anyway, this function $M \mapsto M'$ has good theoretical properties; it's analytic, involutive, and so long as $A$ is row-stochastic and $X$ is column-stochastic, it follows that $A'$ is row stochastic and $X'$ is column stochastic. Going beyond theoretical considerations, I'll note that this transform shows up in a lot of real-world applications, whenever you're trying to perform binary classification based on an imperfect test.

> **Example.**
>
> If
>
> - $M(1,1)$ is the probability of the test coming up positive assuming you have the disease
> - $M(1,2)$ is the probability of the test coming up negative assuming you have the disease
> - $M(1,3)$ is the probability of having the disease
> - $M(2,1)$ is the probability of the test coming up positive assuming you don't have the disease
> - $M(2,2)$ is the probability of the test coming up negative assuming you don't have the disease
> - $M(2,3)$ is the probability of not having the disease
>
> then
>
> - $M'(1,1)$ is the probability you have the disease assuming that the test comes up positive
> - $M'(1,2)$ is the probability you don't have the disease assuming that the test comes up positive
> - $M'(1,3)$ is the probability that the test comes up positive
> - $M'(2,1)$ is the probability you have the disease assuming that the test comes up negative
> - $M'(2,2)$ is the probability you don't have the disease assuming that the test comes up negative
> - $M'(2,3)$ is the probability that the test comes up negative

It's straightforward to generalise the function $(M \mapsto M')$ so that it can be applied to any augmented square matrix in which the denominators don't vanish.

**Question.** Does this transform (and/or the matrix it produces) have a name?

**Addendum 5th Septemeber, 2020.** I think I'll call it the *conditional dual* for now. I remain very interested in this notion, and would love to hear from anyone who knows more about it.

Comment: These are called [linear fractional transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation) the most famous of which being Mobius transformations on complex domains.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I was actually thinking of the Mobius transformations, but I couldn't find a connection. Thanks for the link!